# How can I assign a variable using $expect_out in TCL/EXPECT?

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

If I want to match `DEF_23` using the following regexp:

```
expect {
    -re "DEF_\[0-9]*"
    set result $expect_out(1,string)
}
```

why does it say `no such element in array`?
How does `$expect_out` work, and how can I capture the `DEF` using a regexp and assign it to the variable `result`?

Comment: Did you mean to have extra braces around the `set` line? Otherwise it's a very strange use of `expect` indeed…

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're looking for `expect_out(0,string)` -- the array element `1,string` would be populated if you had capturing parentheses in your regular expression.

The [expect manpage](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) documents the use of  *expect_out* in the documentation of the **expect** command:

> Upon matching a pattern (or eof or full_buffer), any matching and previously unmatched output is saved in the variable *expect_out(buffer)*. Up to 9 regexp substring matches are saved in the variables *expect_out(1,string)* through *expect_out(9,string)*. If the **-indices** flag is used before a pattern, the starting and ending indices (in a form suitable for **lrange**) of the 10 strings are stored in the variables *expect_out(X,start)* and *expect_out(X,end)* where X is a digit, corresponds to the substring position in the buffer. 0 refers to strings which matched the entire pattern and is generated for glob patterns as well as regexp patterns.

There is an illustrative example in the manpage.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the above explication is not precise!
Check this example:

```
$ cat test.exp
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 5
log_user 0

spawn bash

send "ls -1 db*\r"
expect {
  -re "^db.*$" {
    set bkpfile $expect_out(0,string)
  }
}

send_user "The filename is: $bkpfile\n"

close
$ ls -1 db*
dbupgrade.log
$ ./test.exp
can't read "bkpfile": no such variable
    while executing
"send_user "The filename is: $bkpfile\n""
    (file "./test.exp" line 15)
$
```

The test result is the same when $expect_out(1,string) or $expect_out(buffer)is used.
Am I missing something or this is the expected behavior?

Comment: If somebody is still curious why this example above does not work, check answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37255077/1788304

Answer (score 0):

Aleksandar - it should work if you change the match to "\ndb.*$".

If you turn on exp_internal 1, you will see the buffer contains something like this: "ls -1 db*\r\ndbupgrade.log\r\n08:46:09"

So, the caret (^) will throw your pattern match off.