# TCL/Expect - How to spawn bash and control it OR why expect clausule does not see send clausule results

Tags: bash, tcl, expect, spawn

How can I control bash with Expect? My Expect script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

# ENABLE DEBUGGING
exp_internal 1


set timeout 10
log_user 0

spawn bash -i
sleep 5
send "ls -1 db*\r"
expect {
  -re "^db.*$" {
    puts $expect_out(0,string)
  }

  timeout {
    send_error "Script has reached the 'timeout' branch\n"
  } 
}
```

But I always get this output which is caused by time out:

```
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {4740}
send: sending "ls -1 db*\r" to { exp4 }
Gate keeper glob pattern for '^db.*$' is 'db*'. Activating booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "^db.*$"? Gate "db*"? gate=no

expect: does "Agent pid 6228\r\nIdentity added: /home/wakatana/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/wakatana/.ssh/id_rsa)\r\n\u001b[?1034h\u001b]0;~/scripts\u0007\r\r\n\u001b[32mwakatana@ANTARES \u001b[33m~/scripts\u001b[0m\r\r\n$ ls -1 db*\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "^db.*$"? Gate "db*"? gate=yes re=no

expect: does "Agent pid 6228\r\nIdentity added: /home/wakatana/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/wakatana/.ssh/id_rsa)\r\n\u001b[?1034h\u001b]0;~/scripts\u0007\r\r\n\u001b[32mwakatana@ANTARES \u001b[33m~/scripts\u001b[0m\r\r\n$ ls -1 db*\r\ndbupgrade.log\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "^db.*$"? Gate "db*"? gate=yes re=no

expect: does "Agent pid 6228\r\nIdentity added: /home/wakatana/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/wakatana/.ssh/id_rsa)\r\n\u001b[?1034h\u001b]0;~/scripts\u0007\r\r\n\u001b[32mwakatana@ANTARES \u001b[33m~/scripts\u001b[0m\r\r\n$ ls -1 db*\r\ndbupgrade.log\r\n\u001b]0;~/scripts\u0007\r\r\n\u001b[32mwakatana@ANTARES \u001b[33m~/scripts\u001b[0m\r\r\n$ " (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "^db.*$"? Gate "db*"? gate=yes re=no
expect: timed out
Script has reached the 'timeout' branch
```

File that I am trying to `ls` exists:

```
$ ls -1 db*
dbupgrade.log
```

PS: This was inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26520645/1616488) question

Comment: Looks like something's up with the line-aware matching. What version of expect is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Expect`, the `^` and `$` mean very differently:

> Note  that  in  many editors, the `^` and `$` match the beginning and
>   end of lines respectively. However, **because expect  is  not  line
>   oriented,  these  characters  match  the beginning and end of the
>   data (as opposed to  lines)  currently  in  the  expect  matching
>   buffer.**

You can do like this:

```
[STEP 101] # cat foo.exp
spawn bash --noprofile --norc
sleep 1
send "ls -1 db*\r"
expect {
    -re {[\r\n]+(db.*?)[\r\n]+} {
        send_user "\n>>> $expect_out(1,string) <<<\n"
    }
}
[STEP 102] # ls -1 dbupgrade.log
dbupgrade.log
[STEP 103] # expect foo.exp
spawn bash --noprofile --norc
bash-4.3# ls -1 db*
dbupgrade.log

>>> dbupgrade.log <<<
[STEP 104] #
```

Comment: It _might_ work if you were to use this RE (here in Tcl-quoted form): `{(?n)^db.*$}` — the leading `(?n)` enables newline-sensitive matching.

Comment: @DonalFellows: Just tried `{(?n)^(db.*?)$}`. It almost worked but the result would include the `\r` char. So seems like `$` only considers `\n` chars. By the way I cannot easily remember this kind of advanced RE syntax. Usually I only use the simple RE syntax. :)